# What is "policy crumb"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning "policy crumb"?
"That's just a tragic economic policy crumb since the middle class won't be touched by it ..."  " I believe it's more a policy crumb being thrown to the media in the Administration's upcoming 'strike 1st' mantra ..."  "Clinton supports the status quo and only rarely tosses the base a policy crumb ..."  "Another policy crumb that featured was the idea that firms bidding for major government contracts should have to commit to providing ..."  "For decades, immigration hard-liners have felt sidelined and taken for granted by Republican presidential candidates, left with dog whistles and policy crumbs."

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the metaphor of some people getting the cake and others getting only the leftover crumbs. In the updated parlance of "policy crumbs," the people gobbling up or dividing the cake among themselves make a conscious effort to placate the people deprived of a substantial share of the feast by selecting particular crumbs of policy and presenting them to people excluded from the table, in the expectation that these crumbs will satisfy them. The policy in question may be a law against burning the national flag, a promise to crack down on fraudulent voting, or some other sop.

Eric Patridge, *A Dictionary of Clichés*, fifth edition (1978) has this crumb-related entry:

> **crumbs from the rich man's table.** Trifles given to the poor by the rich; a slight consideration shown by the fortunate to the unfortunate: mid C. 19–20. In allusion to *Luke*, xvi. 21, '(A certain beggar named Lazarus) desiring to be fed with the crumbs which fell from the rich man's table'.

The subject comes up in the area of political policy because, in politics, certain party constituencies have major policy desires but no practical say in the party's actual policy on these matters. It often turns out that the popularly desired policy is incompatible with the party elite's interests—so if those goals are the slices of cake, the people excluded from the table aren't going to get any.

Nevertheless, to retain the favor of the relatively powerless party members, the elites may offer them policy crumbs, which the elites view not as major substantive goals to be achieved but as symbolic points of solidarity between them and the rest of the party to be emphasized in slogans, speeches, and political advertisements.